# Android combine Onclick 2 TextView

Tags: android, textview, click, listener

I have 2 `TextView`s, I want to start a method only after clicking the TextView `tvSX`, and then clicking the TextView `tvDX`.  I hope I have explained well. thanks

```
    tvSX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView50);
    tvSX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    tvDX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
    tvDX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //start method after click tvSX and tvDX
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think, you want,the first TextView to be clicked before the second one..right..? if so, please check my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Boolean flag=false;
tvSX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView50);
tvSX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       flag=true;
    }
});

tvDX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
tvDX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(flag){
          flag=false;
          //start method after click tvSX and tvDX
        }
    }
});
```

What I have done is, I declared a `Boolean` variable which is initialised to `false`. The flag is set to true only if the first TextView is clicked. And, in the onClick() of the second `TextView`, the value of the flag is checked, and if it is `true`, then the method is called.